# Read *.txt file with German text, show it in my GUI -- characters with umlauts not correct

Tags: c++, mbcs

My world is: MFC, Visual Studio C++, using MBCS character set.   Generally using CString as my favorite string type, but sometimes std:string as well.

I can put German words in my string table and they show up in the GUI just fine - full of lovely umlauts and other accents.   But if I have a *.txt file containing German text with umlauts, when I read it in (using CStdioFile) and then show it in the GUI, the umlauts and other special characters do not print nicely, instead things like  fÃ¼r  showing up (should be "fur" with an umlaut on the u).

How can I read a *.txt file of German text and show it in the GUI?  Thought this was simple.  I could swear I've done it before without issue.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How are you reading it? What is the file encoded as? What are you decoding as? Please provide an [mre]

Comment: 1) bytes per character - is it 2 (std::wstring) ? 2) Font

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsserver/en-US/8a14aafa-6e0b-480b-a7d4-7a8754b6c99a/convert-a-utf8-file-to-utf16-via-multibytetowidechar?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues ?

Comment: Despite its name, Multi Byte Character Set (MBCS) is a character encoding, not a character set. See [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding#MBCS) for further information.

Comment: This guide may help you: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that your input file is encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), whereas your viewer is interpreting it as a single-byte encoding using code page [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

When encoding the string

`für`

in UTF-8, you get the following bytes:

`0x66 0xc3 0xbc 0x72`

The characters `f` and `r` are each encoded into one byte, whereas the character `ü` is encoded into two bytes.

These bytes correspond to

`fÃ¼r`

in code page Windows-1252.

In your question, you stated that `fÃ¼r` is the output that you are getting for the string `für`. Therefore, what I have stated seems to be the most obvious explanation for the output.